# Kernel Dying when importing unstructured.partition.pdf

Tags: python, kernel

I tried the following import but my kernel dies all the time, how can i solve this problem?

```
from unstructured.partition.pdf import partition_pdf
path = 'data/llama.pdf'
raw_pdf_elements=partition_pdf(
    filename=path,
    extract_images_in_pdf=True,
    infer_table_structure=True,
    chunking_strategy="by_title",
    max_characters=4000,
    new_after_n_chars=3800,
    combine_text_under_n_chars=2000,
    image_outpur_dir_path='images/'
)
```

Issue in first line, but i needed to implement raw_pdf_elements line, then some issue occured because of the tesseract path, then i installed following

```
pip install tesseract
pip install tesseract-ocr
```

After that my kernel started to dying.
Exit

```
> 00:01:01.922 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died
> ExitCode: undefined, Reason:  00:01:01.922 [info] Dispose Kernel
> process 35807. 00:01:01.945 [info] End cell 98 execution after
> -1709672459.206s, completed @ undefined, started @ 1709672459206
```